# Unable to authenticate users via Social login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am having difficulty authenticating users via facebook and google in a Laravel 5.8 API application that uses `passport`. To achieve the social login, I did the following
1. Added the package to app project's dependencies `composer require laravel/socialite`

2. Added the configuration for both facebook and google in config `services.php`
3. Added routes to handle redirect to provider and callback in  `web.php` like so

```
Route::get('/auth/{provider}', 'AuthController@redirectToProvider');

Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', 'AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

4. Added the following methods to my `AuthController`

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    // store provider callback in a variable
    $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    // check if user exist in social account table
    $socialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->id)->where('provider_name', $provider)->first();

    // return user if account exist else create new user
    if ($socialAccount) {

        return response()->json(['token' => $socialUser->token, 'user' => (new UserResource($socialAccount->user))]);
    } else {
        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $socialUser->name,
            'lastname'  => $socialUser->name,
            'username'  => $socialUser->email
        ]);

        if ($user) {

            SocialAccount::create([
                'provider_id'   => $socialUser->id,
                'provider_name' => $provider,
                'user_id'       => $user->id
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json(['token' => $socialUser->token, 'user' => new UserResource($user)]);
    }
}
```

Testing both login returns the expected data and user is created in `users` table while provider info is stored in `socialaccounts` as intended.

The real issue is that when I run a test in post man by passing in the token from provider, the app screams `401 unauthorised`. What I want is to have the user authenticated when the social login is successful. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

After create or return exist user, you should call `\Auth::login($user)` to auth this user.

Comment: I thought I could `\Auth::login($user)` can also be done using `auth()->login($user, true)`, right? I believe since the app uses `Passport` for authentication, I should be exchanging the provider token with passport for the app's generated token. But I am stuck at this point